# Overhead rainshower

Tags: plumbing

I would like to run pex up from the 3way diverted up to the attic to an elbow, then about 3 feet place ceiling fixture for shower head.  I live in Florida and my attic is insulated with spray foam   I have a questions:  i have a recessed light also in the ceiling currently, is there any code requirements since PEx would be near electrical?

What is best way to install?

Comment: Please **add more details** about  your plan, it is unclear if you are installing a valve in the attic or not. Water near electrical is a no no. What is the end goal ?

Comment: My end goal is to add an overhead rainshower to a second floor bathroom with the attic above.  I would like to run 1/2 inch PWC off the diverter valve straight up and just into the attic.  Then place a copper curve and come off with more plex about 30 inches and drop back down into the shower.  The recessed lights are currently in the ceiling shower.  Do I need to move the recessed light?